# GDAL Geo-Transform incorrect after I using Register Raster of ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, gdal

I have a .tiff raster and a .shp vector. And I found they are not aligned after loading them into ArcMap. So I used the registration function of ArcMap to add control points to align the raster with the vector.

Then I try to load the updated raster using Python gdal. However, I found the geo-transform is not updated. It's still the original geo-transform.

Here is the screenshot of the aligned raster and vector.
[image]

The up-left coordinate shown in ArcMap is (38.9247391489, -76.985949678), and the xy pixel size is (6.7091663e-07, 5.2166687e-07).

But when I use the code below to load the raster in Python. The geo-transform is still the original one: (-76.98594463470027, 6.709166337247608e-07, 0.0, 38.92473541609244, 0.0, -5.216668697177878e-07). The cropped result is also aligned with the original raster.

```
ds = gdal.Open(tiff_path)
geo_transform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
for i in range(0, ds.RasterXSize, stride):
    for j in range(0, ds.RasterYSize, stride):
        gdal.Translate(os.path.join(output_dir, 'img', f"{id}_{i}_{j}.tif"), ds, srcWin=[i, j, tile_size, tile_size])
```

I think gdal might not have loaded the .aux.xml file. Because when I delete the .aux.xml file, ArcMap also got the original raster, not the registered one. The .aux.xml file contains auxiliary information that cannot be stored in the raster.

The GDAL version is 3.2.2 and ArcMap is 10.6.

Comment: Based on what I've seen you should have no difficulty modifying the GeoTransform array using the parameters copy-pased from ArcGIS properties dialog. Just to be sure though are you sure it's not a coordinate reference system shift, check the spatial reference of the vector, raster and data frame.

Comment: The first thing to do is to test again with a current GDAL version.  Version 3.2.2 is three years old https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.2.2/gdal/NEWS.

Comment: Thank u. I think I found the problem. For some reason, gdal reads the geo-transform information from tiff, but what I need is the geo-transform from tfw file. So I manually read the tfw file and used it to update the tiff geo-transform.

Comment: The "some reason" is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoTIFF can hold much more information than tfw and therefore GDAL prefers to read the georeferencing from the GeoTIFF. That behavior can be controlled as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#georeferencing

> By default, information is fetched in following order (first listed is
> the most prioritary): PAM (Persistent Auxiliary metadata) .aux.xml
> sidecar file, INTERNAL (GeoTIFF keys and tags), TABFILE (.tab),
> WORLDFILE (.tfw, .tifw/.tiffw or .wld), XML (.xml)
>
> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the allowed sources and their priority order
> can be changed with the GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES configuration option (or
> GEOREF_SOURCES open option) whose value is a comma-separated list of
> the following keywords : PAM, INTERNAL, TABFILE, WORLDFILE, XML (added
> in 3.7), NONE. First mentioned sources are the most prioritary over
> the next ones. A non mentioned source will be ignored.
>
> For example setting it to "WORLDFILE,PAM,INTERNAL" will make a
> geotransformation matrix from a potential worldfile prioritary over
> PAM or GeoTIFF.
>
> Minimum support for extracting the CRS from ESRI .xml side car files
> has been added in GDAL 3.7, using the
> metadata.refSysInfo.RefSystem.refSysID.identCode.code CRS code.

If the .tfw file holds the georeferencing that you want use can make GDAL to use it with the configuration option `GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES=TFW`. However, if the best georeferencing is stored into the ESRI style aux.xml file, then you must update your GDAL at least to version 3.7 and use `GDAL_GEOREF_SOURCES=XML`. By your description that seems to be the case. Notice that the support of ESRI XML is documented to be minimal so it may not work for all images.

Comment: That is the reason! thank you so much.